# && does not work with & from background script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have this script:

```
cd foo && git pull && node server.js & && pid=$! && echo "$pid"
```

but bash doesn't seem to like this part: `& &&`...
so I changed it into this:

```
set -e
cd foo
git pull
node server.js &
pid=$!
echo "$pid"
```

but is there a way to do it with double ampersand `&&` instead?

Perhaps the purpose of the question is if these two are equivalent:

```
cd foo && git pull && node server.js & && pid=$! && echo "$pid"
cd foo && git pull && ( node server.js & ) && pid=$! && echo "$pid"
```

My guess is that they **aren't** equivalent..

Comment: yeah good eye, will fix that

Comment: checking the return status of a backgrounded job (i.e. with `&&`) is pointless; from the bash manual: `If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘&’, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell. This is known as executing the command in the background. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0 (true)`

Answer (score 3):

`cmd1 && cmd2` means "do `cmd1`, and if it succeeded, then do `cmd2`". It isn't known whether a command succeeded until after it's finished running, so it doesn't make sense to both put a command in the background and make the next command's execution depend on whether the first one succeeded.

It sounds like what you actually want to do is "start `cmd1` in the background, then do `cmd2`". This is just `cmd1 & cmd2`.

Thus, here's the command you want: `cd foo && git pull && node server.js & pid=$! && echo "$pid"`

Answer (score 3):

Whitespace is free. IMO, for a long command list like this, newlines aid readability. Even when you want to use `&&` for the logical meaning: for example

```
cd foo &&
git pull && {
    node server.js &
    pid=$!
    echo "$pid"
}
```

That only gets into the `node` block if both `cd` and `git` succeed.

In this scenario, I think that makes `set -e` less useful, as you're handling the return codes yourself.

Comment: not a real answer, just an extended comment.

Comment: np, yeah the bash script I am generating is a string generated in another program, using && to join commands is simply a little bit easier, but I can use newlines in the generated script